# How do I avoid duplicate code while parsing two different objects from a file?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I want to parse a csv file looking like below. The CSV file contains two different types: Planet and Asteroid. Both these types have some unique properties.
[image]

I created a Planet class and an Asteroid class which both inherit from  the abstract SpaceObject class. I created a Parser class that parses my csv file into a list of SpaceObjects. Unfortunately, my class contains duplicate code, and that's what I am trying to avoid.

My code:

```
switch (ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("type"))
{
    case "Asteroid":
        var asteroid = new Asteroid();
        asteroid.Position = new Vector2D(ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("x"), ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("y"));
        asteroid.Speed = new Vector2D(ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("vx"), ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("vy"));
        asteroid.Radius = ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("radius");
        asteroid.Color =
            (Color?)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("color")) ?? Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
        break;
    case "Planet":
        var planet = new Planet();
        planet.Name = ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("name");
        planet.Position = new Vector2D(ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("x"), ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("y"));
        planet.Speed = new Vector2D(ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("vx"), ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("vy"));
        planet.Neighbours.AddRange(ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("neighbours").Split(','));
        planet.Radius = ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("radius");
        planet.Color =
            (Color?)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("color")) ?? Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unknown SpaceObject Type");
}

string ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader(string header)
{
    return fields[columnDictionary[header]];
}

double ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader(string header)
{
    return StringConverter.ToDouble(ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader(header));
}
```

As you can see my Planet and Asteroid object are exactly the same, besides that Planet contains two unique properties (name and neighbours). I was thinking about using the Factory or Builder pattern, but I don't want to create a function with nine parameters. How can I avoid this duplicate code in an elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply put them under the switch:

```
SpaceObject spaceObject;

switch (ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("type"))
{
    case "Asteroid":
        spaceObject = new Asteroid();
        break;
    case "Planet":
        var planet = new Planet();
        spaceObject = planet;
        planet.Name = ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("name");
        planet.Neighbours.AddRange(ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("neighbours").Split(','));
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unknown SpaceObject Type");
}

spaceObject.Position = new Vector2D(ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("x"), ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("y"));
spaceObject.Speed = new Vector2D(ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("vx"), ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("vy"));
spaceObject.Radius = ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("radius");
spaceObject.Color =
    (Color?)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("color")) ?? Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
```

Alternatively, you could use a helper function:

```
switch (ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("type"))
{
    case "Asteroid":
        var asteroid = new Asteroid();
        DeserializeCommon(asteroid);
        break;
    case "Planet":
        var planet = new Planet();
        DeserializeCommon(planet);
        planet.Name = ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("name");
        planet.Neighbours.AddRange(ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("neighbours").Split(','));
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unknown SpaceObject Type");
}

void DeserializeCommon(SpaceObject spaceObject)
{
    spaceObject.Position = new Vector2D(ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("x"), ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("y"));
    spaceObject.Speed = new Vector2D(ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("vx"), ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("vy"));
    spaceObject.Radius = ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("radius");
    spaceObject.Color =
        (Color?)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("color")) ?? Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! My compile throws an error (Token is invalid) on ```spaceObject.Color = (Color?)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("color")) ?? Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);``` How can I fix this?

Comment: @Frogical Please give the exact error message? This code is copied from your question.

Comment: System.FormatException: 'Token is not valid.' on the line that I copied above.

Comment: Oh, it's a runtime exception, not a compiler error? I suspect this is caused by trying to parse a value which can't be parsed as a color. Without more details it's hard to help, but it's likely that this also affected the code in your question.

Comment: Okey so the error throws on ```(Color?)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("color")``` ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("color") returns "grey". So there is something wrong with converting from string?

Comment: "gray", not "grey". ColorConverter recognises "gray", but does not recognise "grey".

Answer (score 3):

By moving the duplicated code outside the switch:

```
SpaceObject spaceObject;
switch (ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("type"))
{
    case "Asteroid":
        spaceObject = new Asteroid();
        break;
    case "Planet":
        var planet = new Planet()
        {
            Name = ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("name"),
            Neighbours = new List<string>();    
        };
        planet.Neighbours.AddRange(
             ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("neighbours").Split(','));
        spaceObject = planet;
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unknown SpaceObject Type");
}
spaceObject.Position = new Vector2D(ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("x"), ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("y"));
spaceObject.Speed = new Vector2D(ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("vx"),ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("vy"));
spaceObject.Radius = ReadDoubleFromCellBasedOnHeader("radius");
spaceObject.Color =
    (Color?) ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(ReadStringFromCellBasedOnHeader("color")) ?? Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! Neighbours (in Planet) is a List<string>. So I have to initialise it first. Like this: new List<string>(). How can I initialize the Planet object with neighbours? (your current code does not work)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please note, however, that Ideally, `Neighbours` should be initialized in `Planet`'s constructor. Even better, that constructor should take in an IEnumerable<string> and `Neighbours` should be exposed as a get only property of type `IReadOnlyList`.